# How can I write an Existential version of a Universally quantified function?

Tags: haskell, reflection, constraints, dependent-type

I've got a Dependent Type problem I'm trying to solve, and I've shrunk it down to the following caricature, of removing an index from a sized vector:

**TL;DR** Given `rmIx`, how can I write `someRmIx`?

```
rmIx     :: forall ix n a. Vector (n+1) a -> Vector n a
someRmIx :: forall ix   a. SomeVector   a -> SomeVector a
```

In the `someRmIx` version, I need to get a witness of the constraints in the `rmIx` function, and, if I can't meet those constraints (eg you can't remove from `Vector 0 a`), then return the `SomeVector` unchanged.

```
module SomeVector where

import qualified Data.Vector.Sized as V
import Data.Vector.Sized
import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Proxy
import Type.Reflection
import Data.Type.Equality
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)
import Data.Data (eqT)

data SomeVector a = forall n. KnownNat n => SomeVector (Vector n a)

-- | Remove an index from an existentially sized 'Vector'.
someRmIx :: forall (ix :: Nat) a m. KnownNat ix => SomeVector a -> SomeVector a
someRmIx (SomeVector (v :: Vector n a)) =

  --------------------------------------------------
  --------------------------------------------------
  --------------------------------------------------
  -- WHAT DO I DO HERE???
  --------------------------------------------------
  --------------------------------------------------
  --------------------------------------------------
  case  ???????  of
    Nothing -> SomeVector v
    Just Refl -> SomeVector $ rmIx @ix v


-- | Remove an index of a 'Vector'.
rmIx :: forall (ix :: Nat) n a (m :: Nat).
  (ix <= n,  -- in my actual code I clean this up with GHC.TypeLits.Normalise
  KnownNat ix,
  (ix + m) ~ n,
  ((n - ix) + 1) ~ (1 + m),
  (n + 1) ~ (ix + (1 + m))
  )
  => Vector (n+1) a -> Vector n a
rmIx v = l  V.++ r
  where (l :: Vector ix a, r' :: Vector (n-ix+1) a) = V.splitAt' (Proxy @ix) v
        (r :: Vector m a) = V.drop' (Proxy @1) r'


----------
-- * Tests

myV :: Vector 5 Int
myV = let Just v = V.fromList [1,2,3,4,5]
      in v

test1 :: Vector 4 Int
test1 = rmIx @2 myV

test2 :: SomeVector Int
test2 = someRmIx @2 $ SomeVector myV
```

The necessary fanfare to compile the above:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compare the [`natVal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:natVal) to `0` and then `unsafeCoerce`. No other choice. You can wrap it in a mildly safer type signature, as in [`sCmpNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-natural-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Natural.html#v:sCmpNat) or similar.

Comment: I was hoping that  I could build `Refl` witnesses of each constraint that `rmIx` wants (using the `constraints` or `reflection` or `singletons` package?). Ex I can compare `natVal == 0` but then I still need to make sure `ix < n`. Is that too Dependently Typed for haskell atm?

Comment: @Josh.F Yes, the answer for lifting all the other comparisons to the type level is also `unsafeCoerce`. But if you've done a good job wrapping it, hopefully you only have to wrap it once, and can use the safer version many times. (It is definitely a bit unfortunate. GHC is certainly within its power to provide primitive operations with the right type and behavior, but they've chosen not to, possibly because they're unsure what the right collection of primitives is.)